# How can I enumerate non-localhost, non-127.0.0.1 IP addresses/domains that point to my Tomcat/SpringMVC Instance?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, url, localhost

In my spring application running on **Tomcat** I have an API that sends a link via **SMS** to a user to verify the phone number. My production server has a public IP and domain name that is reflected in this code:

```
context.getRequestURL().toString().replace(context.getRequestURI(), context.getContextPath());
```

so the URL generated based on this will be perfect in production. However when I am **debugging locally**, the link ends up starting with http://localhost:8080/MyApp which is NOT clickable from other computers on the local network (read my mobile phone that received the link via SMS).

*Is there a way to catch a list of "non localhost/127.0.0.1" addresses pointing to the server where the app happens to be running, for the purpose of reaching it on local network while debugging locally?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer:* No.

*Long answer:* You can iterate the servers IP addresses, but that won't help you, because those might be internal IP addresses on your local network (e.g. `10.29.38.47`), and are mapped (NAT'd) by the firewall, so the IP address of the server, as seen from the Web, is different (e.g. `192.0.2.5`).

Even if you use a service such as [What's My IP Address?](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) to find your external address, it will still only give you one of many potential addresses.

If you want your server code to be able to build a fully qualified URL to itself, you need to specify that in a configuration file, and read the value from there.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of knew all that, perhaps I was not spesific enough in my Q. I meant simply for local debugging purposes, its enough to just ge any old local IP except 127.x.y.z or any old domainname except "localhost" that is reachable locally. I updarted my Q top be more spesific

Comment: The code you have will use the URL used to access the webapp to build the qualified URL. If you don't want it to say `localhost`, then don't use `localhost` to access the webapp. E.g. if your PC is named `MyWorkPC`, then access your webapp using `http://MyWorkPC:8080/MyApp`.

Comment: How could i not catch that! Thank you, I can just forget this Q now.